# Archaic words used in haiku

Tags: poetry

My teacher who practices haiku told me that in haiku they still use the [traditional names for months](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar#Common_names). I was wondering which other words are still used in haiku.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar one would be [Kigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kigo) (season names)

- Kigo list - [http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/季語一覧](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%A3%E8%AA%9E%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)
- Kigo collections - http://www.geocities.jp/tokihikok/masaji/haiku/kigo/